# Java: Float Formatting depends on Locale

Tags: java, formatting, floating-point, locale

I live in Belgium. And generally, in mathematics, we write our decimals with a comma like this: 3,141592
And that is also the result when I **format** the float.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%f", 3.141592));
```

So, the `.` is replaced by a `,` like so: `3,141592`. So always when I need a point instead I have to add something like this: `String.format("%f", 3.14).replace(',','.');`

So, the question is: is there a way to change the Locale which makes every formatter in  Java use a point, instead of comma?

Thanks

---

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

prints

```
nl_BE
```

Comment: Do you want to only change the number formatting or is it okay if everything else changes to, say, US locale as well?

Comment: Interesting I want to see that, what is your defaultLocale ??

Comment: @Thilo: If it is possible: only the number formatting.

Comment: Actually, are you sure System.out.println(float) and Float.toString() behave like this? Because they are specified to not be locale-dependent: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, indeed, I was wrong. **I changed the question.**

Comment: ` Locale.setDefault(new Locale("nl_BE"));        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());//set correctly        System.out.println(3.4565);`//prints normally with  DOT

Comment: @org.life.java: I know. I said I was wrong. This happens when I format a float.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try using `String.format(Locale.US, "%f", floatValue)` for just setting locale used during formatting.

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution, but would be wide reaching across the entire Locale, would be to set the system Locale to US or UK. Example.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

Since you have changed the question, then you simply specify the local with your print method.

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%f", 3.141592));
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you get comma as thousands separator, and it becomes very confusing for French or Belgian users. Our TouhsandsSeparator is space, and comma is our decimal separator.

Comment: Alternatively use `String.format(Locale.US, "%f", floatValue)` for just setting locale used during formatting.

Comment: @rodion: Can you add your answer as a real answer?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: sure deal;)

Answer (score 7):

It may be useful to look at
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html
which contains a number of options for precise output of strings using Locale where necessary

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass
>   of NumberFormat that formats decimal
>   numbers. It has a variety of features
>   designed to make it possible to parse
>   and format numbers in any locale,
>   including support for Western, Arabic,
>   and Indic digits. It also supports
>   different kinds of numbers, including
>   integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4),
>   percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be
>   localized.

It is often useful to route input and output through bespoke routines. Here is one from the JAMA library (http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)

```
   public void print (PrintWriter output, int w, int d) {
      DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
      format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
      format.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
      format.setMaximumFractionDigits(d);
      format.setMinimumFractionDigits(d);
      format.setGroupingUsed(false);
      print(output,format,w+2);
   }
```

By using this you can be sure that future problems and enhancements are likely to be addressed

Answer (score 1):

For formatting numbers, you really should not rely on `toString()`. Use `String.format()`, the factory methods in `NumberFormat`, or `DecimalFormat`, which allow you to control how numbers are formatted (the first two by choosing a Locale) without relying on some global setting.

Comment: toString is reliably locale-independent.