# What is wrong with this String formatter line?

Tags: java, string.format

```
String result = String.format( "% % % | %-20s| %25s | $%,8.2f | %5d | %-s", thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay, 
                    eventName, eventVenue, ticketPrice, ticketsRemaining, eventType);
```

ints: thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay, ticketsRemaining.

Strings: eventName, eventVenue, eventType.

double: ticketPrice.

I have verified that all the fields are properly initialized.  This line should output to this format:

```
2012-01-20 | Penguins-Capitals    |      CONSOL Energy Center | $   92.35 |    15 | NHL
2012-08-05 | Chickenfoot          |    Riverplex Amphitheatre | $   62.50 | 1,273 | Concert
```

The formatter is not complete, but I get failures when I try to run it, so there is some syntax error in there.  I am not very good with formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that you add always the type after `%`, in this case its `%d`

```
String result = String.format( "%4d-%02d-%02d | %-20s| %25s | $%.3f | %5d | %s", thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay, 
                eventName, eventVenue, ticketPrice, ticketsRemaining, eventType);
```

For making a `,` instead of a `.` watch this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553633/java-float-formatting-depends-on-locale).

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a fatal error when I attempt to debug your revised formatter.  Is the '$%,8.2f' field in the right format?

Comment: no, should be $%4.3f or $%.3f depending on the chars before the ','

Comment: Still a no go.  Here is the entire class (self-contained) http://pastebin.com/gJEM76Dh