# Sort in ascending order three floating point numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Crescente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double primo = in.nextDouble();
        double secondo = in.nextDouble();
        double terzo = in.nextDouble();
        if(primo > secondo && primo > terzo) {
            if(secondo > terzo) {
                System.out.println(primo+" "+secondo+" "+terzo);
            }else {
                System.out.println(primo+" "+terzo+" "+secondo);
            }
        }else if(secondo > primo && secondo > terzo) {
            if(primo > terzo) {
                System.out.println(secondo+" "+primo+" "+terzo);
            }else {
                System.out.println(secondo+" "+terzo+" "+primo);
            }
        }else if(terzo > primo && terzo > secondo) {
            if(primo > secondo) {
                System.out.println(terzo+" "+primo+" "+secondo);
            }else {
                System.out.println(terzo+" "+secondo+" "+primo);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

My program works if you enter integer numbers, but if you enter floating point numbers it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at poo.Crescente.main(Crescente.java:8)
```

I don't know why it gives me this error since I used `nextDouble` for all of the variables which are all `double`. Please help.

Comment: You typed something in the console that could not be parsed to a `double`. Please provide what you are inputting

Comment: @GBlodgett I've just noticed that it works if I use a comma instead of a point, like this: "4,1" instead of "4.1". Why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. For me it works if I use `4.2` but throws an error if I do `4,2`

Comment: @GBlodgett I'm from Italy, maybe it's because of that. Here we use the comma for floating point numbers. Anyway, when it prints the three numbers in ascending order, it prints them with a point. It's very strange

Comment: Hmm looks similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553633/java-float-formatting-depends-on-locale

Comment: Why don't use just use `nextFloat` then?

Comment: @NicholasK same issue.

Comment: Use `.` instead of `,` while inputting the numbers

Comment: @NicholasK If I use the comma it works

Comment: That's most likely because of the LOCALE being set to `LOCALE.ITALY`, try using this `in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);` before the declaration of your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your default locale is set to `LOCALE.ITALY` as you are from Italy. Change it to the following

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
// rest of the code
```

I was able to run the program with comma separated numbers (4,2) and decimal separated numbers (4.2) by toggling with the `Locale.ITALY` and `Locale.ENGLISH` respectively.

From the doc's :

> ```
> useLocale(Locale locale)
> ```
>
> Sets this scanner's locale to the specified locale.